# <hr> not displaying at all on IOS Safari and regular android browser.

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, horizontal-line

So i have a:

```
<div class="divHr">
<hr size="0.01">
</div>

.divHr hr{
display: block;
width: 100%;
border-top: 0.25px dotted #CCCCCC;
}
```

If i view it on Chrome / IE / Firefox - additionally it works great on google chrome on mobile devices. 
If i view the site on Safari (IOS) or the standard Android Browser, the HR doesn't display at all. 
I have tried not displaying the border using `border: 0px;` and changing the `size="0.01"` to 1, but it still doesn't display - so it isn't a problem with borders. `

I'd really appriciate some help on this one, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I have not experienced this before myself, but when working with IOS and such I always add `appearance: none;` into my CSS.

I hope this works for you.

More information about the appearance property
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

Best regards,

Comment: Now i've tried it, and nothings works.
I think that the problem isn't that its appeared wrong, it just doesn't display at all. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @HappyDane and what about giving it a fixed height? Via CSS (!)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i found a solution. 
Instead of using `<hr>` just make a div and style it like this:

```
.hrDiv{
border-top: 1px dotted #CCCCCC; 
width: 100%;
height: 0.01px;
border-top-style: dotted;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
border-bottom: none;
color: #CCCCCC;
display: block;
border-color: #CCCCCC;
```

}